# Haskell map/sortBy/findIndex etc. for Arrays instead of Lists

Tags: arrays, list, haskell, functional-programming

I can see that it's possible to write functions like map/sortBy/findIndex and some other List-related functions for Arrays instead (at least those indexed by integers.)  Is this done anywhere in the standard library, or would I need to roll my own?

I need to use an array in my program for the in-place update, but there are also several locations I'd like to use some of the above list functions on it.  Is converting back and forth between the two the best solution?

(The arrays I've been looking at are from Data.Array.IArray.  I'm also happy to use any other array library that implements this functionality.)

Comment: "I need to use an array in my program for the in-place update" - in place update is an implementation detail...why do you *really* need arrays? Space constraints? Time constraints? Trying to implement an algorithm that depends on in-place update?

Comment: You're right, that was badly phrased.  I would like to be able to easily update the element at a given index n.  Of course, I can write a function to do this for a list, but it's inefficient in general and I can't find a default implementation, so it doesn't seem "Haskellish".  I was wondering what the "Haskellish" data structure was that provided list-like functionality, but with efficient built in update-by-index.

Comment: you should check out [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you have a look at the [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) and [vector-algorithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms) packages. They contain very efficient implementations of many common operations on `Int`-indexed arrays, in both mutable and immutable variants.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for.  I've also found Data.Sequence, do you know how these compare?

Comment: @CoreyStaten we must be on the same brainwave. I just asked [Does Data.Vector replace Data.Sequence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013275/does-data-vector-replace-data-sequence)

Comment: @CoreyStaten: Data.Sequence is implemented as a finger tree, while Data.Vector is a "true" array. As such, Data.Vector supports constant time indexing and will usually have less overhead, while Data.Sequence supports constant time manipulation at the ends and is more suited for queue-like operations.

Answer (score 4):

`fmap` (from `Control.Monad`) is sort of like a generic version of `map` that works on anything that supports the `Functor` type class.  `Array` supports that, so you should be able to use `fmap` instead of `map` for array.

As hammar says, the vector and vector-algorithms are probably a better way to approach the problem if you need to consider indexed arrays.