# Does Data.Vector replace Data.Sequence?

Tags: haskell, vector, sequence

I've been quite a fan of [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html). But as I've been learning about [Data.Vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9/doc/html/Data-Vector.html), it seems that it can do everything Data.Sequence can, but better, plus it can do more stuff. Should we be deprecating Data.Sequence and preaching Data.Vector? Are there any good reasons for using Data.Sequence over Data.Vector?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

None of these data structures can replace the other; `Data.Sequence` and `Data.Vector` are actually at diametrically opposite ends of the data structures available for representing sequences.

- `Data.Vector` is a contiguous array of elements. This means small memory footprint and O(1) lookup but terrible mutation, concatenation and copying (O(n) each). (Mutation can be O(1) if you drop persistence.)
- `Data.Sequence` on the other hand is a purely functional tree. This means higher memory usage and less locality, but it supports fast access and mutation O(log n) and awesome concatenation O(log(min(n1,n2))) and copying.

The choice of data structure really depends on the task at hand here.

- Processing large streams of elements in linear fashion or with random lookup is best done with `Data.Vector`.
- If you need to split, concatenate and change your elements a lot, use `Data.Sequence`.

Comment: Actually, if you use the `ST` monad, mutation of `Vector`s becomes extremely easy.

Comment: Just a simple example, you can implement an efficient queue or a deque with `Data.Sequence` but not with `Data.Vector`.

Comment: Sequences also offer splitting (not just slicing) logarithmic in the size of the smaller piece. Their `fmap`, `<*>`, and (recently) `fromFunction` have lazy performance characteristics that vectors can only dream about, and their `replicate` and `*>` are, additionally, like the Tardis—bigger on the inside. So `replicate n v` takes only O(log n) time and space, and as of today, the version of `*>` on GitHub can cycle N copies of a sequence of length L with only O(log N+log L) time and additional space.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing a prefix seems like something `Seq` is better at than `Vector`. `snoc` on `Vector` is O(n).

Comment: Well, `Vector` has stream fusion and stuff, which `Seq` doesn't has.

Comment: @FUZxxl I'm certainly not advocating `Seq` *over* `Vector`! The point is that by natively sharing prefixes, `Seq` is able to more efficiently work with persistent data that is going to be split and/or appended.

Comment: @FUZxxl: even with stream fusion, in most cases snoc and cons will require copying the entire array with a Vector, which is not the case for Data.Sequence.